# How do I align my control using programmed constraints

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nslayoutconstraint

What I am trying to accomplish is fairly simple in the storyboard, but I couldn't get it to work through code only - which is necessary for my particular problem.

## My code:

```
        scrollView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.TopAnchor, 50).Active = true;
        scrollView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.BottomAnchor, 50).Active = true;
        scrollView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.LeftAnchor, 50).Active = true;
        scrollView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.RightAnchor, 50).Active = true;
        scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

        View.AddSubview(scrollView);
```

## What I am trying to do:

In the end I want to position myself inbetween what resembles the Top+Bottom Layout guides in the storyboard - the code does not reflect this. I used this.Top(/Bottom)LayoutGuide, which essentially produced the same error.

## Why do I want to do this?

My layout needs to adapt to orientation changes - constraints seem to be the way to go there. Using the layout guides seems to be working in the storyboard too somehow - so it must be doable in code too? Also right now the navigation + tab bars both overlaw the scroll bar.

## I'm getting this error message:

(this might help people who come here from google because of a similar issue)

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSGenericException Reason: Unable to activate 
constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x174274080 "UIScrollView:0x102245400.top"> and 
<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x1702707c0 "UIView:0x10135e760.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  
Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal. ...
```

If someone would be kind enough to push me into the right direction I would very much appreciate it. I can't seem to find the correct anchor to pass to the constraint yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add subview first. Then you can add constraints. It is also necesarry to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
View.AddSubview(scrollView);
scrollView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.TopAnchor, 50).Active = true;     
scrollView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.BottomAnchor, 50).Active = true; 
scrollView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.LeftAnchor, 50).Active = true; 
scrollView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.View.RightAnchor, 50).Active = true;
```

Comment: Yes - this works. I changed some parameters (-50 on right, -50 on bottom) to get it to render the way i want it to, but the problem was indeed that i attempted to add constraints prior to them being added to the view tree. Thank you!